# How to make ribbon cable?

Tags: modifiers

I've been trying to make a twisted ribbon cable using curves, the array modifier and the simple deform modifier, and I think I've come close but I just can't get the effect in the reference image.

This is the ribbon so far:
[image]

Here are my modifier settings:

[image]

Here's the reference photo:
[image]

As you can see, the cable in my .blend is not convincing and too uniform in the twist without that nice frazzled look of the reference image.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** A simpler improved file has been added with a screw modifier and with the other modifiers is completely flexible and editable. I did not add the noise though that is easy enough to do.

[image]

**The original answer:** Complex meshes and curves can get messy very quickly and I have tried to make a simple setup here. It uses a crude mesh created from screwing some circles around a vertical line/mesh...

[image: screw]

...and adding an array modifier.

[image: array]

A subsurf is added for smoothness, but I also added a noise texture to displace the mesh a bit.

[image: noise plus displace]

A new curve was created and added via the modifiers to original mesh.

[image: curve modifier]

This gives the freedom to move the mesh to the desired shape. The points of the curve can be used to manipulate the general volume with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

[image: curves]

The last part I cheated with another mesh as I think the transition can be obscured. It is duplicated to suggest more bulk and can of-course be messed with to suggest unique cables.

[image]

It's neither pretty or refined but hopefully gives you some ideas.

**Updated** file:

[image]

**Orignal** file:

[image]

Comment: Absolutely incredible.  Thanks so much for finding a solution to something that perplexed me for days!  But I have to ask; how did you get the circles to bend so nicely with the screw modifier?  I've come up with something but it has an angle of 2498 and 512 steps...I think I might be doing something wrong here :)

Comment: The screw tool (I don't think it can be called a modifier as it can only be used once) had 9 steps and 360 degrees. The Array modifier gives it the length and makes it easier for the curve modifier to deform later.

Comment: Ohhh OK I see.  I don't have much experience with the screw tool but I do have some with the screw modifiier.  Obviously different purposes.  Thanks again!

Comment: To be honest forgot about the Screw modifier - probably easier! After 360 degrees use 'Iterations' to increase the length - that way you don't need the Array. The Curve modifier also seems to work fine that way. The only problem I had is that I needed to Apply the Screw modifier to create different materials. Still always more solutions, than just one  ...

Comment: Updated the answer and added a new file. Screw modifier was a good call -  managed to keep it editable. By filling the faces in edit mode, different materials can be used without needing to apply the modifiers.

Comment: Yes I found you had to apply the modifier too which sucks but like you said, always more solutions!  Thanks for adding that to the answer.  That will help others.